# how many ways to multiply n-tuples?

Tags: group-theory, arithmetic

Let $G$ be a group and $a,b,c,\ldots$ elements of $G$. How many different ways are there to multiply elements in $G$, preserving the order?

I mean, two elements ----> 1 way: $ab$

three elements ----> 2 ways: $(ab)c$; $a(bc)$

four elements ----> 5 ways: $((ab)c)d$ ; $(a(bc))d$; $(ab)(cd)$; $a(b(cd))$; $a((bc)d)$

$n$ elements----> how many ways?

Note: we assume we can multiply only pairs of elements, so expressions like $abc$ don't make sense.

Comment: Count where you're putting in parentheses as if the spaces between them are boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you're asking how many different binary trees with $n$ unlabeled nodes are there, as each multiplication expression yields such a tree and vice versa.

[Wikipedia has the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Combinatorics):
$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$, (n+1) is the number of elements, $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number.

However, this number does not agree with the image size of the map which takes $n$ elements from an abelian group $G$ and multiplies them, as there are inverse elements: $ab$ may equal $cd$ for $\{a, b, c, d\} \subseteq G, |\{a, b, c, d\}| = 4$ if $a = b^{-1}$ and $c = d^{-1}$.